# How to edit a TextView which has been dynamically added?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am currently developing a counter app. By pressing the "add" button a new row of certain elements are added. The text view along with 2 buttons are 3 of the elements. I have 2 buttons either side of the textView number, when i press the button on the left side it adds one to the TextView. This works fine But when i dynamically add a new row, when i press the button it changes the value of the first dynamically added row instead of the row i clicked the button on. How can it be so that it gets the row the button was clicked on and adds to that specific row. Here is the code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;

    private int numtest = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);
    }
    public void onAddField(View v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
        // Add the new row before the add field button.
        parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
    }

    public void addone(View v){
        numtest+=1;
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
        t.setText(numtest+"");
    }

    public void subtractone(View v){
        numtest-=1;
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
        t.setText(numtest+"");
    }

}
```

field.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:inputType="textWebEditText"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/type_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:entries="@array/types"
        android:gravity="right" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:onClick="addone"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/subtract_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:onClick="subtractone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_field_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#555"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onAddField"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:text="Add Field"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: From where are you calling `addone()`..?

Comment: don't initialize the textviews in methods. do it in onCreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should track at which index in your parent layout the button is clicked a simple approach is view **tag**

```
public void onAddField(View v) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
 // Add the new row before the add field button.
 //put index tag on your view
rowView.findViewById(R.id.add_button).setTag(parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1)
rowView.findViewById(R.id.substract_button).setTag(parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1)   
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
    }
```

now u have that index to trace you can get respected view to update

```
public void addone(View v){
        numtest+=1;
        View parent = parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(v.getTag());  
        TextView t = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        t.setText(numtest+"");
    } /// similarly for other method substract
```

hope this work for you

Comment: Thanks it worked. But, i am now having this problem where the number on the second line adds on from the previous lines number instead of starting from 0 again.

Comment: you mean numtest variable?

Comment: yes the numtest variable. what i am asking is there a way to create a separate numtest variable for each new dynamically added row. since the problem occurs because the numtest value is the same for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a counter variable and initialise it with zero,increase it by one each time user clicks on the add button and then set its value as id of the newly created rowView by `rowView.setId(counter)`and then you can uniquely identify each row by its id and hence you can control the counter which is supposed to be increased/decreased.